# datapower cannot be installed in docker

Tags: docker, ibm-datapower

I installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 64 Bit. And then i followed the instructions in the link https://developer.ibm.com/datapower/docker/

- docker pull ibmcom/datapower:latest
- After the download completes, the DataPower image appears in my registry.
- When i type the following command it does not respond it waits forever.

  ```
  $ docker run -it -v $PWD/config:/drouter/config -v $PWD/local:/drouter/local -e
   DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true -e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true -e DATAPOWER_WORKE
  R_THREADS=4 -p 9090:9090 ibmcom/datapower
  time="2017-03-02T18:03:24+03:00" level=info msg="Unable to use system certificat
  e pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires 4096 MB memory and 2 chip dedicated to the default machine. Make sure that virtualization is enabled. Then make sure that you installed docker successfully, try **docker images** command to see that docker is working or not. If working, stop your machine with **docker-machine stop** command. Then goto virtual box, and change the settings of your default machine (4096 MB memory and 2 chip). It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one - https://github.com/ibm-datapower/datapower-tutorials/blob/master/getting-started/start-with-docker.md

Make sure you allocate 4GB RAM and 2 Core CPU for Datapower.

Docker Command -

```
docker run -it \
  -v $PWD/config:/drouter/config \
  -v $PWD/local:/drouter/local \
  -e DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true \
  -e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true \
  -p 9090:9090 \
  -p 9022:22 \
  -p 5554:5554 \
  -p 8000-8010:8000-8010 \
  --name idg \
  ibmcom/datapower
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/awasen/entry/DataPower_on_Docker_Toolbox?lang=en

(Written by me...)